# How to play an audio stream of bytes in android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing an android app that will play mp3 files.  However the mp3 files are encrypted on the sd card or sqlite.  Either ways, after decryption, i'll have a stream of bytes.  How do i play them? MediaPlayer does not take inputstream as parameter, so i cannot consider that.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this? Check the accepted answer as it talks about playing `byte[]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte

Comment: the stream shouldn't be available to the user.  So, if i make a file, then the user can access the file and this is not a good idea for this particular project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to store the stream to file system; then you could try using `setDataSource`  method of [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29)

```
FileInputStream rawmp3file= new FileInputStream(yourByteArrayAsMp3File);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rawmp3file.getFD());
```

If you could switch to PCM audio source, have a look at [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class.

> The AudioTrack class manages and plays
>   a single audio resource for Java
>   applications. It allows to stream PCM
>   audio buffers to the audio hardware
>   for playback. This is achieved by
>   "pushing" the data to the AudioTrack
>   object using one of the write(byte[],
>   int, int) and write(short[], int, int)
>   methods.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be easy. I've done it before on BlackBerry so I bet it's doable on Android too.

If I were you I'd register a new provider for the a custom "encryptedmp3:" protocol. Then I would specify this in a data source for the MediaPlayer:

```
mediaplayer.setDataSource(this, URI.parse("encryptedmp3://....yourfile"));
```

I'm not sure how to create a new protocol handler on Android.

I hope this helps a little bit.

Emmanuel

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [BASS library](http://www.un4seen.com) (free for non-commercial use).
Here is a link for Android: http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=13225.0

There is [BASS_StreamCreateFile](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_StreamCreateFile.html) function:

```
HSTREAM BASS_StreamCreateFile(
    BOOL mem,
    void *file,
    QWORD offset,
    QWORD length,
    DWORD flags
);
```

Parameters:

```
mem     TRUE = stream the file from memory.
file    Filename (mem = FALSE) or a memory location (mem = TRUE).
```