# Play audio from buffer

Tags: android, audio, audio-player

I want to play audio from a buffer.
Something like using the AudioRecord to record the audio into buffer and play
it from the buffer.

Is there a way of doing it?
In the MediaPlayer there is no such option.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class. Its interface is very similar to that of `AudioRecord`, except that the `AudioTrack` can only use buffers of type `byte[]` and `short[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use temp file as described in solution here:

[Android - Playing mp3 from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte)

or if your file comes from the internet (referenced by URL for example), you may use:

`setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)`

presented in the same question.