# Play Byte array in MediaPlayer - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to play an audio file with the MediaPlayer. I want to play byte array in MediaPlayer. How can I do this? I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte)

```
 public void writeSamples(byte[] samples, int length) 
{
  //  track.write( samples, 0, length);
    File tempMp3;
    try {
    tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("kurchina", ".mp3");
      tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
      fos.write(samples);
      fos.close();
      // Tried reusing instance of media player
      // but that resulted in system crashes...  
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

      // Tried passing path directly, but kept getting 
      // "Prepare failed.: status=0x1"
      // so using file descriptor instead   
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

But its not playing audio. It is just generating many files in SD Card. And giving this **error**:

```
 06-06 11:02:59.191: E/MediaPlayer(1831): Unable to to create media player
 06-06 11:02:59.191: W/System.err(1831): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.:      status=0x80000000
 06-06 11:02:59.201: W/System.err(1831):  at    android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
 06-06 11:02:59.201: W/System.err(1831):  at   android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:749)
 06-06 11:02:59.201: W/System.err(1831):  at   org.vinuxproject.sonic.SonicTest$1.run(SonicTest.java:178)
 06-06 11:02:59.201: W/System.err(1831):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Please help me. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add your code snippet here and someone will be able to help.

Comment: I'd recommend trying the setDataSource variant that takes an offset and length in addition to the FD.  Does the generated mp3 file play in the music application?  Also, deleteOnExit isn't useful in Android/Dalvik.

Comment: No file is not playing in my application. Please help me

Comment: Does the `samples` array contain mp3-encoded data, or just raw PCM data?

Comment: Does this work if you specify a directory with `createTempFile(String, String, File)`? Is there a difference between external/internal? Where are the temp files being created now?

Comment: Tried using a directory of getFilesDir(), but still have the same problem.

Comment: Okay so if the byte array is a .mp4 file, then it seemingly works fine, but I am using a byte array that is a wave file and it won't play. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the @dagalpin comment above - try the overload variant of setDataSource

Answer (score 8):

Based on your comments, you are using a WAV file for streaming. Conventional [WAV has a header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) at the beginning of the file and the rest of the file is *pure data*. If you don't include the header part, then the parameters from it need to be provided to the player the be able to interpret the data (number of channels, samples per second, block size, etc.) As a result, a WAV file alone is not streamable, the parameters must be fed into the player.

[MPEG-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp4) on the other hand has been specified to be capable of streaming. It contains well identifiable segments that are possible to be played alone, so as long as the data chunk contains a header, the data after it can be playable. In addition to it's good compression ratio, this is one of the reasons why many internet radios use it.

`MediaPlayer` in Android is a high level component and the low level parameters that would be required for playing a WAV chunk are not accessible. If you need the source to be WAV and cannot use other [streamable formats](http://www.orb.com/en/music/audio-streaming/audio-streaming-formats.html), then you can try the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class or [OpenSL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842803/low-latency-audio-playback-on-android) for even lower level access.
For AudioTrack this is a very good tutorial: http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/a-simple-synth-in-android-step-by-step-guide-using-the-java-sdk/

Comment: Hmm... audioTrack may sound like the way to go.

Comment: the wordpress link is "dead" in that the blog is now private

Comment: @ForceGaia we may try to request access to the blog or try to find some new tutorial. If you have any suggestion, feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

After write a byte on file :
you can play  from this function:

```
 void playSound(int resid) {
        MediaPlayer eSound = MediaPlayer.create(context, resid);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(resid);
        eSound.reset();
        eSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        try {
            eSound.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                    afd.getLength());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            eSound.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        eSound.start();
    }
```

And you can get file information from here:

```
byte[] getFileInformation(String filepath) {
        MediaPlayer eSound = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(filepath));
        eSound.reset();
        eSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        try {
            eSound.setDataSource(filepath);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            eSound.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int duration = eSound.getDuration() / 1000;

        int height = 480;
        int width = 640;
        height = eSound.getVideoHeight();
        width = eSound.getVideoWidth();

        eSound.release();
        File f = new File(filepath);
        int size = (int) f.length();
        byte[] b = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(convertIntToByte(size), 0, b, 0, 4);
        System.arraycopy(convertIntToByte(duration), 0, b, 4, 4);
        System.arraycopy(convertIntToByte(width), 0, b, 8, 4);
        System.arraycopy(convertIntToByte(height), 0, b, 12, 4);
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void playMp3(byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) 
{
    try 
    {

        File path=new File(getCacheDir()+"/musicfile.3gp");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
        fos.close();

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getCacheDir()+"/musicfile.3gp");

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        String s = ex.toString();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```