# Precisely Sync Looped Audio with Animation in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, audiotrack, opensl

**Question:** 
Is there any way to use AudioTrack and setLoopPoints() to configure a loop with accuracy based on samples/frames per millisecond?

**Edit:** I understand that perfect accuracy can't be expected from the processing power that most android devices possess. I'd like, however, to get an average loop time close to the tempo's "real" interval in milliseconds as this is how I've based an "animation" that should also sync with the tempo (the animation is a SurfaceView which redraws a line's coordinates over the duration of the tempo's interval).

**Details:**
I'm trying to use AudioTrack with setLoopPoints to create a accurate metronome. To do this, I'm using two wav files (Tick and Tock) to fill a byte[] array to feed to AudioTrack. Consider an example in 4/4 time where I would fill a byte[], once with Tick beginning at [0] and three times with Tock (using arrayCopy()) to [length/4],[length/2], and [3*length/4], and assume that the wav data will not overlap each other.

**Rough example of what my code does:**

```
// read each wav file's header into its own ByteBuffer (with LITTLE_ENDIAN order)
// ... then get the size of the audio data
tickDataSize = tickHeaderBuffer.getInt(40); 
tockDataSize = tockHeaderBuffer.getInt(40); 

// allocate space for one loop at the current tempo into a byte[] array (to be given to    AudioTrack) 
// e.g. 22050hz * 2 Bytes (1 per channel) * 2 Bytes (1 per 8 bit PCM sample) = 22050*4 Bytes/second
//      If my tempo were 60 BPM I'd have 88200 Bytes/second (where 1 second is the whole loop interval);
// 110 BPM = 48109.0909091 Bytes per loop interval (where 1 loop interval is 0.54545 seconds)

int tempo = 110;
int bytesPerSecond  = sampleRate * 2 * 2;
int bytesPerInterval = (int)((((float)bytesPerSecond * 60.0F)/(float)tempo) * 4); 

byte[] wavData = new byte[bytesPerInterval];

// ... then fill wavData[] as mentioned above with 1*wavOne and 3*wavTwo

// Then feed to an instance of AudioTrack and set loop points
audioTrack.write(wavData, 0, bytesPerInterval);
int numSamples = bytesPerInterval/4;
audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, numSamples, -1);
audioTrack.play();
```

Hopefully you've begun to see the problem. **With certain tempos, I get only static playing in the loop** (but only during the 1st and 3rd Tock [2nd and 4th sample in the loop]).

**The static stops if I:**

- Don't fill the byte[] with any wav data but keep the bytesPerInterval
  and numSamples the same (silent loop of correct duration).
- Set bytesPerInterval = bytesPerInterval % 4 (thus losing tempo accuracy)

**Examples of working (no static) and not working (static) tempos and their required number of frames (Consider one second = 88200 frames):**

```
tempo: 110 (static)
wavData.length: 192436 
numFrames: 48109

tempo: 120 (no static)
wavData.length: 176400 
numFrames: 44100

tempo: 130 (static)
wavData.length: 162828 
numFrames: 40707

tempo: 140 (no static)
wavData.length: 151200 
numFrames: 37800

tempo: 150 (no static)
wavData.length: 141120 
numFrames: 35280

tempo: 160 (static)
wavData.length: 132300 
numFrames: 33075

tempo: 170 (static)
wavData.length: 124516 
numFrames: 31129

tempo: 180 (no static)
wavData.length: 117600 
numFrames: 29400
```

If the answer to the question is "no, you can't use setLoopPoints() to configure a loop accurate to any millisecond", then I'd like to know of any other options. **Would OpenSL ES in NDK, SoundPool, or MediaPlayer be more appropriate for generating a precise loop?**

**Edit 2:** I've narrowed down the location causing the static issue:

```
// Assume a tempo of 160 BPM which requires byte[132300]
wavStream1 = this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tick);
wavStream2 = this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tock);

ByteBuffer headerBuffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(44);
ByteBuffer headerBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(44);
headerBuffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
headerBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
wavStream1.read(headerBuffer1.array(), 0, 44);   
wavStream2.read(headerBuffer2.array(), 0, 44);
int tickDataSize = headerBuffer1.getInt(40); 
int tockDataSize = headerBuffer2.getInt(40);    

byte[] wavData = new byte[bytesPerInterval * 4];

byte[] tickWavData = new byte[bytesPerInterval];
byte[] tockWavData = new byte[bytesPerInterval];

wavStream1.read(accentWavData, 0, tickDataSize);
wavStream2.read(normalWavData, 0, tockDataSize);

System.arraycopy(tickWavData, 0, wavData, 0, bytesPerInterval);
System.arraycopy(tockWavData, 0, wavData, 33075, bytesPerInterval);
System.arraycopy(tockWavData, 0, wavData, 66150, bytesPerInterval);
System.arraycopy(tockWavData, 0, wavData, 99225, bytesPerInterval);
// bytesPerInterval of 33075 and 99225 (or any odd number) will be 
// static when wavData is played 

AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(3, 22050, 12, 2, wavData.length, 0);
audioTrack.write(wavData, 0, wavData.length);
audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, bytesPerInterval, -1);
audioTrack.play();
```

**Most importantly, I'd like to understand why audio data beginning at an odd index of wavData generates static instead of the expected sound and if there is any remedy for this.**

Comment: To the millisecond? That's *probably* impossible no matter what you do. The hardware just isn't made for that. Related reading: [Low-latency audio playback in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14842803/752320)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your edits, I think the reason odd indices cause a problem is because you are creating the `AudioTrack` with `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` (the "2" you pass in the constructor). That means every sample should be 16 bits. Try it using "3" or `ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` if the samples are 8 bits.

Comment: When I read your comment I thought "..has to be it!". It would make perfect sense; however, I tried using ENCODING_PCM_8BIT as well as toying with the channels, sample rates, etc., even modifying WAV files to fit each circumstance, but only ended up with more static. I believe the reason for this could be the device I'm testing on (Nexus 7 2012) does not support 8 bit PCM as warned by the AudioTrack docs. I value your suggestion but believe there has to be a better alternative. For the moment I'm sticking to adding a "%2" to the byte[], which adds roughly 0.00005 ms to each loop.

Comment: I thought that had to be it, too :) My only other inclination would be that native & OpenSL _might_ yield better results. On the native side, AudioTrack and OpenSL should be sharing the same underlying mechanisms, but I'm not yet familiar enough with AudioTrack source to rule out there being a hang-up somewhere. As to the device not supporting 8 bit PCM, that may be so, but couldn't you substitute 16 bit sources to test? I'm curious because I have a related project in the works...

Comment: Also, if you haven't read over the link Generic Holiday Name provided, do so. It lends credence to the idea that OpenSL is the way to go.