# Seeking carification on how buffers are handled when streaming raw PCM audio with openSL on Android

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

I have read in several places that for streaming audio you need to enqueue at least 2 buffers, at least when using the SLBufferQueueItf or SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf.
Using 2 buffers seems to be the most common method.  One buffer being played, while another gets filled up with new data.  That makes perfect sense in theory.

In the native-audio sample project in the NDK, there is this comment:

> "for streaming playback we would typically enqueue at least 2 buffers
>   to start"

Does that mean that playback doesn't start until 2 buffers have been enqueued?

I tried enqueing 2 buffers, by calling Enqueue(....) twice consecutively, but the bufferqueue callback gets called before I can enqueue the second time.

If I need to actually queue up 2 buffers to start playing, at what point can I start filling up the third buffer?  The third buffer is supposed to be reusing the first buffer I enqueued.

I have my SLDataLocator set up like so:

```
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bufq = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
```

In practice it seems like the process goes like this:
Engueue first buffer -> when callback comes (which is instantly) queue up second buffer
  -> wait for second callback to enqueue third buffer

I don't see how enqueing 2 buffers is even possible, aside from enqueing one then another in the callback.  Also, I am using the native buffer size for my device.

Also, I don't think "enqueing" is a word.

Edit:  Some info at this commit for 4.4: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/+/92e53bc98cd938e9917fb02d3e5a9be88423791d%5E!/
Which I just found in this useful SO post: [Low-latency audio playback on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842803/low-latency-audio-playback-on-android)