# HTML5 Audio delay - Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, audio

I'm trying to implement a button press sound using HTML5 `<audio>` element and a javascript trigger. I am getting bit of a delay between when the button is pressed and when the sound plays. The sound is meant to be user feedback for a successful press so any delay is unacceptable.

The implementation works fine on all windows devices, but there is a varying amount of delay on any android device I've tested on.

**HTML:**

```
<audio id="button_click" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/button.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.buttonClick = function(){
   var audio = document.getElementById('button_click');
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
};
```

The extra audio.load(); line is a workaround for the problem of HTML5 audio elements only playing once on Android devices.

Any thoughts on a workaround?  If there is no workaround, any thoughts on how to implement an audible feedback for button clicks in a browser based single page app?

Comment: Which browser you were using? What's the android version?

Comment: How much of a delay? Android has a persistent issue with audio latency. There are other questions with deal with this same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842803/low-latency-audio-playback-on-android

Comment: @ Sabbir Using Android Chrome running on JellyBean 4.3.  Also tested on  KitKat but not yet on Lolipop.

Comment: @Kyle The delay is around a second but as this is a feedback for a user interaction that's a long time.  If I was playing a song....no big deal.  Thanks for the link.  Reading now.

Comment: The preload attribute is boolean on mobile and loads only meta information and endbyte for length. Try caching the audio via a link tag in the head, then call the click.