# Playing sound fast as possible

Tags: android, xamarin

Now like does the question says, I need a way to play a small sound that lasts for like 1 second or less to play really quickly/fast in my Xamarin Android app. I am using .mp3 files and MediaPlayer class, is there any way to get as fast as possible to play a particular sound?

Comment: then create custom media player

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Low-latency audio playback on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842803/low-latency-audio-playback-on-android)

Comment: Ref: https://www.khronos.org/opensles/