# Playing video downloaded from ASP.NET server in android

Tags: android

I want to play video in android. The video is downloaded from the ASP.NET server and is received as a String. How to play the received video in android using default player.

```
String img = wbsi.SoapAction(new String[] { "XXXX", "XXXX",
                    "XXXX" },
                new String[] { pref.getString("XXXX", "n.a"),
                            "XXXX", XXXXXX });
```

The above code calls the webservice class and downloads the video file as a string of byte[].

I am successfully able to download the images and view it but facing issues with videos. Tried the solution of [Android - Playing mp3 from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte) and was able to play the audio but not the video

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad solution at all!! traffic is very huge and amount of memory is very huge. you should return a url to video file and set this url to player

Comment: The video file is small (less than 2 mb) and the video is needed to played when the user has no internet connection. Also the video is downloaded during the installation of the app and may be updated when needed. Any suggestions to do this will be highly appreciated

Comment: in this case save video to file (using download manager for example)