# what is maximum size of encoded 64 base file to upload php webservice?

Tags: php, file-upload, base64

I want to develop PHP web service which accept file as base64 string but my main concern is, up to how many max size file can be uploaded as base 64?

Service will be called from android platform. My concern is not browser specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the size limit of a Base64 DataURL image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637395/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-base64-dataurl-image)

Comment: Service will be called from android platform. My concern is not browser specific