# How to convert a ParseFile into a playable 3GP file

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im working on an app which uploads and downloads audio files from www.parse.com. I upload them as parseFile and it works perfect.
When I download the parseFile, how can i convert it to something my android can play it?

Note: I upload the files in format .3gp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `ParseFile` into a `Byte[]` with the `getData()` method.

Then, you can play the song from the `Byte[]` by using this function with some edit (from [Android - Playing mp3 from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte)) :

```
private void play3GP(byte[] 3gpSoundByteArray) {
    try {
        File temp3GP = File.createTempFile("temp_audio", "3gp", getCacheDir());
        temp3GP.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp3GP);
        fos.write(3gpSoundByteArray);
        fos.close();

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(temp3GP);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String s = ex.toString();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot! Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

3GPP is fine as you see in the link. You just have to POST the file with a mime type that indicates what it is. See the curl code using the parse REST Api Posting audio with a 'Content-type' header.

When you do a GET it should come with that mimeType and the media player should be able to handle it with just a URL ref to the parse file.

```
 --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --header "Content-Type: audio/amr-wb; rate=8000"  --data-binary @yourFile.3gp

> POST /1/files/audio HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: api.parse.com
> Accept: */*
> X-Parse-Application-Id: LAbR
> X-Parse-REST-API-Key: kuI9
> Content-Type: audio/3gp
> Content-Length: 39822
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Request-Method: *
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 15:20:41 GMT
< Location: http://files.parse.com/1315e4d8-f302-4337-adbe-/home/rob/Documents/txt/T61A/latest_android_RTP.txd8650ab5c312/cbbafaf3-aabd-4236-9351-9570f56269af-audio
< Server: nginx/1.2.2
< Set-Cookie: _parse_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlNWY1NWY2ODUwNGQ5NWVmYjNhMDk2NTliYTcxYWE0M2E%3D--0ba6fa255619c0bbcd2a8a324509208f26872177; domain=.parse.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 11-Oct-2022 15:20:41 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
< Status: 201 Created
< X-Runtime: 0.111346
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Content-Length: 164
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.parse.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"url":"http://files.parse.com/1315e4d8-f302-4337-adbe-d8650ab5c312/cbbafaf3-aabd-4236-9351-9570f56269af-audio","name":"cbbafaf3-aabd-4236-9351-9570f56269af-audio"}
```

so try uploading with those headers then use the URL from the response to load to MediaPlayer.