# How to play cached byte array in android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I have a Xamarin application which plays remote(internet) audio files using the **MediaPlayer** with the following setup:

```
_mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(mediaUri);
_mediaPlayer.PrepareAsync();
```

Now I would like to change the implementation to also cache files. For the caching part I found a really nice library called [MonkeyCache](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/monkey-cache) which saves the files in this JSON format:

```
{"$type":"System.Byte[], mscorlib","$value":"UklGRhAoAgBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAIARKwAABCxAgAEABAAZGF0YdAnAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+P/4/+z/7P8KAAoA7//v//L/8v8JAAkA6f/p//j/+P8FAAUA6P/o/wEAAQD+//7/5//n ................."}
```

So my MediaPlayer setup has now changed to:

```
if (Barrel.Current.Exists(mediaUri)){
       var audio = Barrel.Current.Get<byte[]>(mediaUri);
       _mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(???);
}else{
       using (var webClient = new WebClient()){
            var downloadDataBytes = webClient.DownloadData(mediaUri);
            if (downloadDataBytes != null && downloadDataBytes.Length > 0)
            {
               Barrel.Current.Add(mediaUri, downloadDataBytes, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
               _mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(???);
             }
        }
 }
```

I would like to play the audio from a byte[] instead of the mediaUri. 
Is there any way to actually play an in memory byte[]?

The only solutions that I could find were to create a **FileInputStream** out of a **File** by using a filepath, but the implementation of the **MonkeyCache** actually hashes the file name, before adding it:

```
static string Hash(string input){
    var md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
    var data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
            return BitConverter.ToString(data);
}
```

Therefore the downloaded bytes, will be saved under:

```
/data/data/com.package.name.example/cache/com.package.name.example/MonkeyCacheFS/81-D6-E8-62-F3-4D-F1-64-A6-A1-53-46-34-1E-FE-D1
```

Even if I were to use the same hashing logic to actually compute the file path myself and use the **FileInputStream** which might be working by what I've read, it would defeat the purpose of using the `var audio = Barrel.Current.Get<byte[]>(mediaUri);` functionality of the MonkeyCache.

However, if that is the only way, I will do it.

Edit: Even with my described approach, it would probably not work right away as even if I compute the right file name, it is still in JSON format.

Edit2: A working solution is:

```
var audio = Barrel.Current.Get<byte[]>(mediaUri);
var url = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(audio);
_mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

The **MediaPlayer.SetDataSource** method has an overload which expects a MediaDataSource object.

> MediaDataSource
>   For supplying media data to the framework. Implement
>   this if your app has special requirements for the way media data is
>   obtained

Therefore, you can use your implementation of the MediaDataSource and feed it your byte array.

```
public class StreamMediaDataSource : MediaDataSource
    {
        private byte[] _data;

        public StreamMediaDataSource(byte[] data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public override long Size
            => _data.Length;

        public override void Close()
        {
            _data = null;
        }

        public override int ReadAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
        {

            if (position >= _data.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (position + size > _data.Length)
            {
                size -= (Convert.ToInt32(position) + size) - _data.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(_data, position, buffer, offset, size);
            return size;
        }
    }
```

which will lead to the MediaPlayer data source to be

```
_mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(new StreamMediaDataSource(downloadedDataBytes));
```

Edit: This only works for API >= 23. I still have to find a solution for API<23(which I still haven't).

Edit2: For API < 23 support I used the

```
var url = $"data:audio;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(downloadedDataBytes)}";
_mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(url);
```

approach.

Comment: Watch out, you are going to run into issues if you intend playing mp4 files that have the header information written at the end - mediaplayer will not be able to do seek operations on the the base64 URI that gets generated!

Comment: Wow. That is indeed correct. I just ran in this issue last night.I was looking for a nice solution. Probably I'll just have to get rid of MonkeyCache and cache files as they come without a JSON serializer over them. I've already tested with the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte and it should work if I stream directly from the file by using the file descriptor.