# How do you get/set media volume (not ringtone volume) in Android?

Tags: android, get, media, volume, android-audiomanager

Is there a way to get/set media volume? I have tried the following:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

but it returns the ringtone volume.

Comment: The answer I provided also pops up the volume dialog which shows when using the hardware volume control.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Instead of `AudioManager.STREAM_RING` you shoul use `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`
This question has already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application).

Comment: A quick example can also be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5446346/491044

Comment: Can you help me on this question about volume? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256364/volume-always-the-same

Answer (score 63):

```
private AudioManager audio;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Override onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have made my day, solution worked very well, exactly what I needed. Just to let everyone know, this shows the popup with Media volume progress bar and allows you to easily select volume in your application. Thank you.

Comment: No problem... You of course can also handle other things with the switch statement too like menu and back button key downs.

Comment: It's too hard. And produces unwanted sound like user changed ring tone volume. The best solutions is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10919403/148387

Comment: The documentation specifically says not to do this: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html "You may be tempted to try and listen for volume key presses and modify the volume of your audio stream that way. Resist the urge."

Comment: It also states: "The type of the audio stream whose volume should be changed by the hardware volume controls. It is not guaranteed that the hardware volume controls will always change this stream's volume (for example, if a call is in progress, its stream's volume may be changed instead). To reset back to the default, use USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE." The documentation seams to have changed focus but it is also nice to have a finite solution which leaves less error: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream(int) . It is good to know though.

Comment: You should not just return `false` as default since this will effectively disable other buttons such as the back button. Instead, `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);`

Comment: Can you help me on this question about volume? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256364/volume-always-the-same

Answer (score 35):

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float percent = 0.7f;
int seventyVolume = (int) (maxVolume*percent);
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seventyVolume, 0);
```

Comment: `getStreamMaxVolume` was useful to set volume.

Answer (score 34):

Have a try with this:

`setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

Comment: Quote: "You may be tempted to try and listen for volume key presses and modify the volume of your audio stream that way. Resist the urge. Android provides the handy setVolumeControlStream() method to direct volume key presses to the audio stream you specify." http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#HardwareVolumeKeys

Comment: This is much better than trying to manage the volume yourself.

Comment: This should definitely be the answer. It also works with Activities that inherit NativeActivity.

Answer (score 19):

You can set your activity to use a specific volume. In your activity, use one of the following:

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);  
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);  
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);  
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);  
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICECALL);
```

Comment: @hanoo also wrote this in his answer a few months ago.

Comment: Can you help me on this question about volume? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256364/volume-always-the-same

Comment: any idea how to find the current volume control stream? from a service for instance?

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to have a volume bar that you want to adjust –similar to what you see on iPhone's iPod app– here's how.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        //Raise the Volume Bar on the Screen
        volumeControl.setProgress( audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                + AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        //Adjust the Volume
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        //Lower the VOlume Bar on the Screen
        volumeControl.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                + AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code will set the media stream volume to max:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Answer (score 3):

To set volume to 0

```
AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
```

To set volume to full

```
AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

the volume can be adjusted by changing the index value between 0 and 20

Comment: The max volume isn't alway `20`. Maybe you can pass a bigger than max value without causing an issue, I don't know. But to get the max use `audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)`.