# How can i make the phone ring even while on quiet mode?

Tags: android

Is there any way to do as the title describes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ringer volume  or change it's profile. Use AudioManager

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do so please?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593552/android-get-set-media-volumenot-ringone-volume