# How do I get the device audio level in percentage on Android?

Tags: android, device, volume

I am trying to get my android app to check if the device's volume (media, not ringer) is lower than 'x' percent, but I am unsure how. I am currently trying this:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
if (volume <0.7) {message};
```

Edit: I want the percentage of the volume, such as 10%/20%...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get/set media volume (not ringtone volume) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593552/how-do-you-get-set-media-volume-not-ringtone-volume-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int currentVolumePercentage = 100 * currentVolume/maxVolume;
```

`currentVolumePercentage` will be your percentage!

Comment: I think you are using integer division by accident. It should be `int currentVolumePercentage = 100.0 * currentVolume/maxVolume;`

Comment: Evaluation order is left to right. So the double constant should be on the left. Otherwise you are just multiplying the integer division result when the "damage" is already done. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html
Upvote appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Same [Trenton Telge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602735/6478047) answer in kotlin function

```
fun getCurrentAudioLevelPercentage(context: Context): Int {
    val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    val currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    val maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    val percentage = 100 * currentVolume / maxVolume
    return percentage
}
```