# how to capture long press volume down key in android?

Tags: android

Just wondering whether anyone could tell me how to capture the long keypress of the volume down key in android.

Elaborated question:

I wanted to create a **BroadcastReceiver** which will receive volume long keypress event. (without any UI interaction). I know it's possible for the search button. is it available for the Volume Keys?

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to create a BroadcastReceiver which will receive volume long keypress event. (without any UI interaction). I know it's possible for the search button. is it available for the Volume Keys? -Thanks

Answer (score 8):

may be below code will help you:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
     // to your stuff here
     return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get the KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN into a BroadcastReceiver? like <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="VOLUME LONG KEY PRESS HERE" />
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

Comment: I dont think if thats possible

Comment: Hi I dont know whats exactly is you requirement but what you can do is using above when you got event in any activity you can create a custom broadcast that the volume key is long pressed and use that in BL

Comment: How do I do it in a service?

Comment: sorry you cant do it in service

Comment: Thanks Bro...You saved my Time...+1 vote  for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Note that to handle onKeyLongPress() you should track event onKeyDown(). and override both of them.
please note the following examples.

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
 @Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        //Do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
}
```

Also note that onKeyDown by default returns false. So by triggering onKeyDown() volume won't be increased.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is in theory possibly to accomplish the capturing of long key presses of the volume button, but is ill advised. The process would involve overriding the onKeyLongPress() method.

As to why it is ill advised: [Volume Control in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application) and [How can I manage audio volumes sanely in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628659/how-can-i-manage-audio-volumes-sanely-in-my-android-app/674207#674207)

It has been discussed before and basically, the keys have default behaviors that should not be overwritten because it is possible to "break the behavior of the volume keys".

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command

adb shell input keyevent --longpress KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN