# Hold down volume button on android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app where if you hold down the volume down button, an action occurs. How would I go abouts doing this? I'm a noob for java, so an example would be excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `onKeyLongPress` in your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
    {
        // to your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

[how to capture long press volume down key in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269628/how-to-capture-long-press-volume-down-key-in-android)

Comment: In Eclipse, there is a shortcut key (Ctrl-Shift-O) to auto manage the imports.
Otherwise you just need to import the classes you use (I can see KeyEvent here).