# Android - Getting volume button long clicks

Tags: android, click, touch, hardware, wait

Can someone please show me a code example about how to get a long click (2 sec for example) on the volume up hardware key?

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

The class that i want to capture the long click with is a Service. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to capture long clicks, this answer might be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5269673/1401257

**EDIT:**

I have never tried to have a key listener inside a service, but with a little help from Google I found this: [Volume change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130455/volume-change-listener)

It seems that normal key events can only be handled from Activities. I do not have time to try this out myself, but for capturing long clicks it might be possible to combine the answer from the link and Lukes answer. 
From what I understand about BroadcastReceivers, you would want to create a receiver, that notify the Service whenever someone click the volume buttons.

Comment: Only a second, if i want to capture this in a Service it wont work. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Optionally you could do something like this:

```
if(clickedDown) {
if(beginningTime + 2000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
// Ok, the button has been clicked down for 2 seconds
}
}
else {
beginningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Applying something like this, you'll be able to define the amount of time to wait.

Comment: The answer above solved it, but can you please look at my comment on it and try to help me out?