# how to control sound in android?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Volume Control in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

i m making an app for music player and i want to increase and decrease volume by using hardware buttons on mobile. so pls tell me any code to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO Use

```
 Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
```

to get an instance of this class.

FOR MORE INFORMATION ,[CLICK HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

Comment: Try to use this "setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);" and put it in onCreate.