# Audio control in Android app

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I am working in an android app and I need to make an `optionMenu` with an option to disable/enable the sounds in the app.

Is it possible in android have full control over the volume of the app?
Is there any method that could do that?
Must I do this with code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453181/android-independent-volume-control). According to that answer, it's not possible. Just don't play the sounds.

Answer (score 1):

By using AudioManager  you can get current volume level and max volume level. At the time of button click/ option select you can control the volume level also. Here is the code.I hope this will help you to set volume.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

To Set Volume

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,vol_level, 0);
```

Comment: But with this, you control the whole device volume or the app volume?   Thanks for your answer

Comment: This will control the device volume

Comment: But what I want is to control the app volume