# How to stop audio for calls and hold on Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: java, embedded, android

I'm developing my first Android app for the Samsung Galaxy Tablet. In order to pass QA the app must be able to integrate with the volume control of the tablet.

Needs to handle:

- volume silder controls master device volume
- audio stops when a call starts
- audio stops when someone presses the 'hold' button

I basically inherited this heap of java code from a dev who went M.I.A. and have little knowledge of the frameworks involved in coding for Samsung devices. Thanks for any assist pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: After picking up another developer's code, I scrapped this project as being ridiculous and started from scratch using UI controls. The real issue is heavily obfuscated here. Please ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> volume silder controls master device volume

check out this question: [Volume Control in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

> audio stops when a call starts

I think this would happen by default. If it does not you'll have to post how you are playing the audio for us to be able to help probably. But also a Samsung Galaxy Tab cannot receive a phone call as far as I can tell. So I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

> audio stops when someone presses the 'hold' button

also not sure what you mean by this one. Like the hold button while in a phone call? Again I am pretty sure none of the Galaxy Tablets can make or receive a phone call. So I don't think users will have access to a hold button

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear there. This is a really simple web app using a custom flash player for videos. This question is based on the Samsung QA team's response. tbh I am just as confused as you are,..

Comment: Are you implementing it as just a website that the users can go to with their stock browser? Or are packaging it as an apk and using a webview to display your content?

Comment: I'm packaging it as an apk with a webview.