# Choose volume channel to change on volume key press

Tags: java, android

In Android, there are normally 3 Audio Volume Channels interesting to the user: Music/Media, Ringtone, and Alarms. Normally, when pressing the hardware volume buttons, the ringtone volume gets set and a dialog with a seekbar is shown accordingly.

But if I have opened the Music app and press the volume buttons, the Media volume channel gets set (and a loudspeaker icon is shown on the seekbar dialog instead of a phone). My question now is, how can I set for my application that is uses the media channel volume control instead of the ringtone channel? Is there a switch for this or do I have to do this manually (catching the volume button strokes)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volume Control in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

Comment: yes it is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling, I found it out for myself.

You can call [setVolumeControlStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29) in the onCreate method of your activity. Example below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    // change the music vol instead of ringtone vol
    // when hardware volume buttons are pressed
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Stream music

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

For Ring tone

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

For more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

Comment: sorry, I don't want to get the volume, but I want to set which volume stream gets modified when the user presses the hardware volume keys.

Answer (score 0):

You use AudioManager and set one of the following:

```
STREAM_ALARM    //The audio stream for alarms
STREAM_DTMF         //The audio stream for DTMF Tones
STREAM_MUSIC    //The audio stream for music playback
STREAM_NOTIFICATION //The audio stream for notifications
STREAM_RING         //The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_SYSTEM   //The audio stream for system sounds
STREAM_VOICE_CALL
```

Like this:

```
myManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: sorry, I don't want to get the volume, but I want to set which volume stream gets modified when the user presses the hardware volume keys.