# Android: Imagebutton, onclick play sound

Tags: android, audio, media-player, imagebutton

I'm a noob trying to work something out and learn from it.

I have two imagebuttons and when i click them I get a kind of "schick" sound rather than the sound files that i have in the /res/raw/ directory.

This is my code:

```
public void button_clicked1(View v) 
{
    text1.setText("1"+width);  

     mp = MediaPlayer.create(GameScreen.this, R.raw.a);   
     mp.start();  
    }


public void button_clicked2(View v) 
{
    text1.setText("2"+height);    
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(GameScreen.this, R.raw.b);   
 mp.start();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Ok, changed the above code to this:

```
 public void button_clicked1(View v) 
    {
        text1.setText("1"+width);  

         mp = MediaPlayer.create(GameScreen.this, R.raw.piano_a);   
             try {
                    mp .prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         mp.start();



        }


    public void button_clicked2(View v) 
    {
        text1.setText("2"+height);    
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(GameScreen.this, R.raw.piano_b);   

            try {
                mp .prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     mp.start();
        }
```

And it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Try this:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

in your main application code. This will tell the `AudioManager` that when your application has focus, the volume keys should adjust music volume ([found that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628659/how-can-i-manage-audio-volumes-sanely-in-my-android-app)).

After that, make sure that your volume is up - it may just be playing the sounds with no volume.

Comment: I put another suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I think i found the problem, the files are WAV files... and am not sure if thats supported

Comment: Nope, not supported: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: [.WAVs are supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Check out the last column of the last supported audio format. There may be another problem. Let me know if your code works with a sound file that isn't a WAV.

Comment: Ok, got it working!!! In the image button went through each property and found something that says "Sound effects enabled", then turned that to false... and the damn thing worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it! You should put that in your original post (on top) or in a separate answer, and I'll delete mine.