# Pause Phone Ringtone while Speaking through Text To Speech and then Resume

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ringtone, android-audiomanager

I am making a caller speaking application which speak caller name using TTS. I want to pause the ringtone while TTS is speaking then resuming the ringtone. From what i have researched we can use `AudioFocus` (hope so). 
Anyway i am using the following code

**Update**

I am using this code now.

```
public void speak(final String talk) throws InterruptedException {
     final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     int musicVolume= audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, musicVolume, 0);
     audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

    int result = tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    });
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");
    tts.speak(talk, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
    System.out.println("speaking after tts is over" + talk+" "+result);

}
```

Although the `Ringtone` is stopped and `tts` is played but after `tts` is played `Ringtone` is not resumed. What should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally after scratching my head for two days i finally did it. For all those who want to implement something like this but are unable to do so here is the code

```
public void speak(final String talk) throws InterruptedException {
    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int ringVolume = audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    int musicVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    currentRingVolume = ringVolume;

    musicVolume = (int) ((musicVolume * seekbarValue) / 100);

    if (PauseRingtone == true) {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 1,
                AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    } else {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                ringVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    }

    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, musicVolume, 0);

    int result = tts
            .setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("done");
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                            currentRingVolume, 0);
                }
            });
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "stringId");
    tts.speak(talk, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
    System.out.println("speaking after tts is over" + talk + " " + result);

}
```

**explaination :-**

`ringVolume` - gets the current volume of the **ringtone** .i.e ringtone volume set in the phone.

`musicVolume` - gets the current volume of the **music**

`currentRingVolume` just retains the `ringVolume`.

**Note-** `STREAM_RING` and `STREAM_MUSIC` are different things. See [image: different volumes]

Now the basic idea is to `mute` the `ringtone` while `TTS` is speaking and then set it to previous value.

`seekBarValue`- is my `SeekBar` which depicts the level of the `TTS` volume w.r.t `musicVolume` and is optional.

`PauseRingtone`- is a `CheckBox Preference` which checks whether we want to pause ringtone while speaking. If `true` is sets the `AudioManager.STREAM_RING` to `1` i.e. `vibrate` else `ringVolume` i.e. `Phone Value`, so both `TTS` and `Ringtone` play at the same time.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,musicVolume, 0)
```

sets the volume of `TTS` to `musicVolume`. After `TTS` has completed speaking i.e. in `onDone()` we set the volume of `Ringtone` back to the `ringVolume` using `currentRingVolume`.

**If my answer helped mark my answer useful.**

Comment: I want to stop or pause the music player if tts starts working and 
restart the music player if tts stops.can you plz help me in this.

Comment: The coding logic is same as I have written, I was pausing ringtone, you need to pause music player. If you are still unable to get an answer, best option would be to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of this focus listener and add this code phoneStateListener class. This will solve your problem.

```
 int mode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
 int musicVolume= audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, musicVolume, 0);
 audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

if(phoneState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
{

 audioManager.setRingerMode(mode);

}
```

Comment: The code is making no ringtone to be played other than tts. But i want to play the ringtone after tts has stopped speaking. How to do that?

Comment: I used `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` on `tts` and then in `onDone()` i used `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);`. But that only put the phone in normal mode. There is no ringtone.