# audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) returns 0

Tags: android, ringtone, android-audiomanager

I am making an Speaking caller name application which pause the ringtone before speaking the caller name using `TextToSpeech`. I am detecting the current `Volume` using

```
int musicVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Mostly this returns `0` but sometimes `15` the correct value. The phone is in normal mode and the volume of phone is full. I need this value to correctly speak the caller name but this unpredictable behaviour is making me crazy.

What wrong am i doing? Isn't this the correct way to detect ringtone volume?

Comment: solved this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17900273/1979347

Answer (score 0):

It places the example below that it functions, volume is of 0 to the 15.

```
public void pegarVolume(){

    AudioManager AudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService (Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int musicVolume = AudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to say? I can't understand what you want to convey here. I already mentioned in a comment that I solved the problem and gave the link.